# Migrating rosbag message

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, rosbag-record, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Guys,

When I was trying to play a rosbag file in ROS Indigo version, I was getting the below error.

```
Waiting 0.2 seconds after advertising topics.../rrrrrr/platform/ros/ros_comm/roscpp/src/libros/publication.cpp:629 Publication::validateHeader() 
[ERROR] [1535722434.248608746]: Client [/my_c] wants topic /topic to have datatype/md5sum [visualization_msgs/MarkerArray/90da67007c26525f655c1c269094e39f], but our version has [visualization_msgs/MarkerArray/d155b9ce5188fbaf89745847fd5882d7]. Dropping connection.
```

After going through the answers.ros blog, I finally found that the ROS version plays an important role in playing the rosbag file. The version which used to collect the rosbag is different from what I am trying to play in.

I am currently working on migrating the message from old to new. I am following the link http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/migration and http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Commandline#check.

I have completed the below steps:

```
rosbag check old.bag -  
the rosdep view is empty: call 'sudo rosdep init' and 'rosdep update'
WARNING: Within rule [GENERATED.update_visualization_msgs_MarkerArray_d155b9ce5188fbaf89745847fd5882d7] cannot migrate from subtype [Marker] to [Marker]..
The following migrations need to occur:
 * From: visualization_msgs/Marker [4048c9de2a16f4ae8e0538085ebf1b97]
   To:   visualization_msgs/Marker [18326976df9d29249efc939e00342cde]
    1 rules missing:
     * From: visualization_msgs/Marker [4048c9de2a16f4ae8e0538085ebf1b97]
       To:   visualization_msgs/Marker [18326976df9d29249efc939e00342cde]
 * From: visualization_msgs/MarkerArray [d155b9ce5188fbaf89745847fd5882d7]
   To:   visualization_msgs/MarkerArray [90da67007c26525f655c1c269094e39f]
    1 rules missing:
     * From: visualization_msgs/Marker [4048c9de2a16f4ae8e0538085ebf1b97]
       To:   visualization_msgs/Marker [18326976df9d29249efc939e00342cde]
 * From: tf2_msgs/TFMessage [94810edda583a504dfda3829e70d7eec]
   To:   tf2_msgs/TFMessage [94810edda583a504dfda3829e70d7eec]
To generate rules, please run with -g <rulefile>
```

Also I have generated a bag migration rule file and saved in myRule.bmr

```
rosbag check -g diagnostics.bmr diag.bag
```

I am getting the error, when I try to fix the bag.

```
the rosdep view is empty: call 'sudo rosdep init' and 'rosdep update'
ERROR: Update rule [carla_rule_v1.bmr:update_visualization_msgs_Marker_4048c9de2a16f4ae8e0538085ebf1b97] has valid set to False.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tmp/ros/bin/rosbag", line 35, in <module>
    rosbag.rosbagmain()
  File "/home/tmp/ros/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosbag/rosbag_main.py", line 883, in rosbagmain
    cmds[cmd](argv[2:])
  File "/home/tmp/ros/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosbag/rosbag_main.py", line 415, in fix_cmd
    migrator = MessageMigrator(rules, plugins=not options.noplugins)
  File "/home/tmp/ros/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosbag/migration.py", line 554, in __init__
    raise BagMigrationException("Cannot instantiate MessageMigrator with invalid rules")
rosbag.migration.BagMigrationException: Cannot instantiate MessageMigrator with invalid rules
```

As per the document:

> If a bag is currently unplayable and non-migratable, it may be necessary to generate rules to bring the bag up to date. See Migrating Messages for the preferred approaches to doing this.

Could you please help me to update the rule file manually.

Thank you,
KK

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302273/migrating-rosbag-message/) by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on ROS Answers with karma: 262 on 2018-09-03

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Choco93](https://answers.ros.org/users/31829/choco93/) on 2018-09-04**:
Do you know which ros version was used to record the bag?

**Comment by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on 2018-09-04**:
@Choco93 Thanks for the reply. No, Unfortunately I dont know the ROS version used to collect the bag file.

**Comment by [Choco93](https://answers.ros.org/users/31829/choco93/) on 2018-09-04**:
This error occurs due to message mismatch. One thing you can do is remove visualization_msgs and reinstall and then try. Other thing can be you clone visualization_msgs from github, switch branch and build and then try. I haven't worked with migration rules so cannot help there.

**Comment by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on 2018-09-04**:
@Choco93 Thank you for the input. I have already tried the first approach, but reinstalling the visualization_msgs did not help. I believe the migration would fix, but not able to find any reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Issue has been fixed by using the below commands

```
 rosbag check
 rosbag fix
```

Thank you,
KK

---

Originally posted by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) with karma: 262 on 2018-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [flash_27](https://answers.ros.org/users/49272/flash_27/) on 2019-11-12**:
Hi, i know it is an old topic. But i have exactly the same issue, and i was hoping you could explain more how you solved the problem. These commands are the one I am trying, but they are without any argument.
How do they work?

**Comment by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on 2019-11-12**:
You need to pass your bag file name.